# How can I obtain a youtube video title from a known id for a webmatrix site?

Tags: youtube-api, webmatrix

I would like to retrieve the title of a video using the YouTube atom feed here:
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/uRTXEjjrOko I would then like to add this title to my database. How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq TO XML is the recommended API for working with XML. You would get the title like this:

```
@using System.Xml.Linq;
@{
    var url = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/uRTXEjjrOko";
    var video = XDocument.Load(url);
    XNamespace media = video.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("media");
    var title = video.Descendants(media + "title").First().Value;
}
```

If you wanted to get the link to a thumbnail, you would do this:

```
var thumbnail = video.Descendants(media + "thumbnail").First().Attribute("url").Value;
```

There are actually 4 thumbnail links. The code above just grabs the first one. Once you have extracted all the values you want, you can use them along with your SQL in the `Database.Execute` method.

Comment: Why did you declare media as XNamespace instead of var?  Just Curious.

Comment: No reason really. I just copied that line of code from an old article of mine (couldn't remember off the top of my head how to declare a namespace properly) and didn't spend any time reviewing the resulting code for consistency or anything.